# iptables - redirect DNS queries

Tags: networking, dns, iptables

I already have the following iptables rules applied in order to masq all of the wlan1 traffic through wlan0.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [48:6144]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [47:6078]
-A INPUT -i wlan1 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i wlan1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o wlan1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i wlan1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar  3 00:54:14 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Mar  3 00:54:14 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:66]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:66]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:651]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10:651]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

What i'm trying to achieve is redirecting all of the DNS queries form input interface wlan1 to some specific ip.

I already tired:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to MYDNSIP:53
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination MYDNSIP:53
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I would appreciate any help

-- 
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allright, after a few tries I have finally achieved the goal.
The key to the success were two rules below:

```
-A PREROUTING ! -s 10.42.0.1/32 ! -d 10.42.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.1:53
-A PREROUTING ! -s 10.42.0.1/32 ! -d 10.42.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.1:53
```

I hope that this will help someone

Comment: The thing is in your question you were only filtering `udp` packets for DNS but DNS uses both `tcp` and `udp` and your answer satisfies that..please select it as the correct answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 0):

Extra sample - Redirect DNS Queries to another server only for certain IP ranges:

```
-A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.12.3/32 ! -d 192.168.12.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.10-10.0.0.240 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.12.3:53
-A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.12.3/32 ! -d 192.168.12.3/32 -p udp -m udp -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.10-10.0.0.240 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.12.3:53
```